# navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I m very new in react native and I m getting this error. Please help!
`navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)`

```js
import { View, Text,Button,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer,CommonActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const GetOtpButton = (navigation) => {
      return (
        <View >

          <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen") }  >
                        <Text style = {styles.text}>Log in</Text>

                    </TouchableOpacity>


        </View>
      )
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        button: {
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: "white",
          width: "100%",
          height: 50,
          borderColor: "#E13C72",
          backgroundColor: "#E13C72",
          borderWidth: 0.1,
          borderRadius: 80,
          // marginBottom: 40,
          // marginVertical: 5,
          // marginTop: 10,
        },
        text: {
          justifyContent: 'center',
          textAlign: 'center',
          color: "white",
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    });

    export default GetOtpButton
```

---------------------App.js------------------

```js
import react from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import SigninScreen from "./src/SigninScreen/SigninScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./src/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SigninScreen" options={{headerShown: false}}>

     <Stack.Screen name = 'SigninScreen' component={SigninScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}}/>
     <Stack.Screen name = 'HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}}/>

     </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>


  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {},
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component `GetOptButton` is not defined as a screen in the navigator, thus the `navigation` object will not be passed to it automatically by the navigation framework. Thus, you have multiple choices here.

**Define it as a screen inside the navigator**

```js
<Stack.Screen name = 'GetOpt' component={GetOptButton} />
```

The framework will now pass the navigation object to the `GetOptButton` component. You can access it as follows.

```js
const GetOtpButton = ({navigation}) => { ... }
```

Now, since `GetOptButton` seems to be a component rather than a screen to which you will navigate, it might not make much sense to define it inside the navigator.

**Pass the navigation object from a screen which is defined in the navigator that uses the `GetOptButton` component**

```js
// this works, since `Homescreen` is defined as a screen in your navigator
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  return (
   <GetOptButton navigation={navigation} />
  )
}
```

Destructure the navigation object inside `GetOptButton` as shown above.

**Use the useNavigation hook**
For some components it might not make sense to pass the `navigation` object from its parent, e.g. if the component is deeply nested. For this cases you can use the `useNavigation` hook.

```js
const GetOptButton = () => {

   const navigation = useNavigation()
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, I m stuck again. Can you please help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72276274/19035343

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing how `GetOtpButton` is used but guessing that navigation is passed as prop to `GetOtpButton` you need to get to navigation like this

```
const GetOtpButton = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View >

      <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen") }  >
                    <Text style = {styles.text}>Log in</Text>
                    
                </TouchableOpacity>
  
      
    </View>
  )
}
```

See that the difference is that `navigation` is surrounded by curly brackets, so later you get the parameter navigation inside the props

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I m still getting this error after adding the curly bracket.
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Comment: Hello thanks for your help but I have found a solution by using useStack

const GetOtpButton = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

Comment: Hello sir, I m stuck again. Can you please help me on this? stackoverflow.com/q/72276274/19035343